# Seemingly Random crashes processing Pointcloud with Point Cloud Library - possibly memory issue?

Tags: memory-management, crash, point-cloud-library

I am doing several steps of reprojections of a point cloud (around 40 Million points initially, ~20 Million while processing). The Programm crashes at seemingly random points at one of these  2 loops. If I run it with a smaller subset (~10 Million Points) everything works fine.

```
//Projection of Point Cloud into a sphere 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr projSphere(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud,int radius) 
        { 
        //output cloud 
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr output(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 
        //time marker 
        int startTime = time(NULL); 
        cout<<"Start Sphere Projection"<<endl; 
        //factor by which each Point Vector ist multiplied to get a distance of radius to the origin 
        float scalar; 
        for (int i=0;i<cloud->size();i++) 
                { 
                if (i%1000000==0) cout<<i<<endl; 
                //P 
                pcl::PointXYZ tmpin=cloud->points.at(i); 
                //P' 
                pcl::PointXYZ tmpout; 
                scalar=radius/(sqrt(pow(tmpin.x,2)+pow(tmpin.y,2)+pow(tmpin.z,2))); 
                tmpout.x=tmpin.x*scalar; 
                tmpout.y=tmpin.y*scalar; 
                tmpout.z=tmpin.z*scalar; 
                //Adding P' to the output cloud 
                output->push_back(tmpout); 
                } 
        cout<<"Finished projection of "<<output->size()<<" points in "<<time(NULL)-startTime<<" seconds"<<endl; 
        return(output); 
        } 
//Stereographic Projection 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr projStereo(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud) 
        { 
        //output cloud 
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr outputSt(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 
        //time marker 
        int startTime = time(NULL); 
        cout<<"Start Stereographic Projection"<<endl; 
        for (int i=0;i<cloud->size();i++) 
                { 
                //P 
                if (i%1000000==0) cout<<i<<endl; 
                pcl::PointXYZ tmpin=cloud->points.at(i); 
                //P' 
                pcl::PointXYZ tmpout; 
                //equation 
                tmpout.x=tmpin.x/(1.0+tmpin.z); 
                tmpout.y=tmpin.y/(1.0+tmpin.z); 
                tmpout.z=0; 
                //Adding P' to the output cloud 
                outputSt->push_back(tmpout); 
                } 
        cout<<"Finished projection of"<<outputSt->size()<<" points in "<<time(NULL)-startTime<<" seconds"<<endl; 
        return(outputSt); 
        }
```

If I do all the steps independently by saving/loading the pointclouds on the harddisk and rerunning the program for each step it also works fine. I'd like to provie the entire source files but I'm not sure how/if it's neccessary.
Thanks in advance

Edit:1
After about a week I have still no idea what might be the issue here, since the crashes are somewhat random, but not really? I tried to test the programm with a different system workload (freshly rebooted,  with heavy duty programs loaded etc.) makes no apparent difference. Since I thought it's maybe a memory issue, I tried o move the large objects from stack to heap (initialising them with new), did also make no difference. By far the largest object is the raw input file, which I open and close by:

```
    ifstream file;
    file.open(infile);
/*......*/
    file.close();
    delete file;
```

Is that properly done, so that after the method is completed the memory is released?

Edit again:
So I try further and further, and finally I managed to put all the steps into one function like this:

```
void stereoTiffI(string infile, string outfile, int length)
    {
    //set up file input
    cout<<"Opening file: "<< infile<<endl;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(infile);
    string line;
    //skip first lines
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
        getline(file,line);
        }
    //output cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    getline(file,line);
    //indexes for string parsing, coordinates and starting Timer
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    float x=0;
    float y=0;
    float z=0;
    float intensity=0;
    float scalar=0;
    int startTime = time(NULL);
    pcl::PointXYZ tmp;
    //begin loop
    cout<<"Begin reading and projecting"<< infile<<endl;
    while (!file.eof())
        {

        getline(file,line);
        i=0;
        j=line.find(" ");
        x=atof(line.substr(i,j).c_str());
        i=line.find(" ",i)+1;
        j=line.find(" ",i)-i;
        y=atof(line.substr(i,j).c_str());
        i=line.find(" ",i)+1;
        j=line.find(" ",i)-i;
        z=atof(line.substr(i,j).c_str());
        //i=line.find(" ",i)+1;
        //j=line.find(" ",i)-i;
        //intensity=atof(line.substr(i,j).c_str());
        //leave out points below scanner height
        if (z>0)
            {
            //projection to a hemisphere with radius 1
            scalar=1/(sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2)));
            x=x*scalar;
            y=y*scalar;
            z=z*scalar;
            //stereographic projection
            x=x/(1.0+z);
            y=y/(1.0+z);
            z=0;
            tmp.x=x;
            tmp.y=y;
            tmp.z=z;
            //tmp.intensity=intensity;
            cloud.push_back(tmp);
            k++;
            if (k%1000000==0)cout<<k<<endl;
            }
        }
    cout<<"Finished producing projected cloud in: "<<time(NULL)-startTime<<" with "<<cloud.size()<<" points."<<endl;
```

And this actually works quit nicely and quickly. In a next step I tried to use Pointtype XYZI because I need to also get the intensity of the scanned points. And guess what, the program crashes at around 17000000 again, and again I have no idea why. Please help

Comment: I investigated a bit further: If I do the steps independently it crashes sometimes, but most of the times it runs through, just taking ages because I have to read/write the big point clouds (~500MB) all the time. Also, it seems to crash at either the first or second loop, every run is different. And the crashes seem to occur somewhere around the 17 Millionth oder 11 Millionth (different every few runs) iteration? I am totally lost here, because it seems so random. Please help

Comment: Ok, so I did a few runs to see if there's any pattern, the loops give an output at each whole hundredthousand (changed the code above). In 15 runs it did always crash in the second loop, alternating randomly between 17900000 and 11900000, it went like this: 179,119,119,179,179,119,179,179,179,179,119,179,179,119,179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Dr. Memory gave me the right hint by giving me a heap allocation error. After  a bit of googling I enabled Large Addresses in Visual Studio (Properties -> Linker -> System)
Everything works like a charm.